# CyanogenMod and soft buttons issue when in fullscreen

Tags: cyanogenmod, themes

I've recently been having a problem with my android phone. After rooting and installing cyanogenmod, I started applying a few themes.

Now, fullscreen or landscape APD appear to mess up the soft buttons. I can't press them properly either. Even after restoring to the system theme, the problem still persists. Here's a screenshot to show you:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I'm attempting to edit in the screenshot but I don't have the permissions to view it - could you re-upload it to imgur? I'd also suggest mentioning what sort of phone, and what specific version of cynogen mod you're using in case the error is specific to that combination. Finally android phone questions are OT here - this may get migrated, but in future you may want to ask other questions of this sort there.